# tomcat JNDI loking up remote EJBs

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jndi, tomcat7, jboss6.x

I have a jboss and a tomcat installed in the same machine (with jboss 6 having port 8080 and tomcat 7 having port 8090) and I am trying to use JNDI lookup from tomcat to obtain the ejb lookups in JBoss. I have checked my EJB beans using the jmx console to make sure they are available. I have denoted them to be @Remote and in JMX console these EJBs are avilable as 
aaaServiceRemote/remote
bbbServiceRemote/remote  etc

I my tomcat, I have put my application war which consists a Service locator and when the application starts the service locator tries to find the EJBs and fails. 
I have put jnp-client and jboss-all-client jar files copied from jboss/client to tomcat/lib folder
I have put a jndi.properties file inside the webapp directory of tomcat consisting of the following entries.

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
```

it seems that tomcat is trying to find the EJBs in its JNDI context not the remote jboss JNDI context.

any help on how this remote looking up can be enabled please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like your jndi.properties file is not read properly.
Have you tried to see whether these properties are passed to the InitialContext object when you create a first JNDI lookup?

What the debug reveals?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mark
The service locating code fails in 
(T)ctx.lookup("aaaServiceBean/remote");
when debugged in tomcat



I have done jndi lookups inside jboss itself where I used the above mentioned jndi.properties settings. but I feel that since we are calling a remote jboss from the tomcat, jndi.properties should be changed as well. something like 
`code`
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,
                              "corbaloc:iiop:1.0@x1devapp63.dev.freightliner.com:2809/NameService");
`code`

Comment: it throws a NamingException, (javax.naming.NameNotFoundException)

Comment: I tried using code without the jndi.properties where I initialized Properties and created the context and got an error 



'SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to com.MyBean'

Comment: Hi, I believe the configuration that you've provided are the correct configurations. It should work like this: You create initial context and jnp implementation automatically brings you the classes you need (that's why you've specified the NamingContextFactory). I just tend to think that your InitialContext fails to get initialized with these properties for some reason.

Comment: Yet another reason can be that the jboss's jndi tree is not "homogenous", I mean that the scope of the your binding depends on where you put it, this means, for example, you can't lookup for DataSource bindings only because they reside in a specific place in jndi tree (I admit I don't remember exactly where it should be, but you can see it easily in your jboss). If you're outside the tomcat, can you just lookup the jboss resource? You can try to write a simple test with "main" method that would invoke the remote bean and use the jndi.properties that you've supplied

Comment: Hi Mark,
after completely copying all the jars in the jboss_home/client folder to my tomcat's lib I was able to perform the remote lookup. as I have read and understood, after jboss 4, the single jboss-client jar which was available had been distributed among several jars. it has become very confusing to pickup the jars that are only required for the lookup. I tried using all the client jars, such as jboss-client, jnp-client etc but until I made the decision of moving all the jars to tomcat, the lookup was failing.

Comment: is this a good practice in terms of design perspective? if we need to move to a new app server in future, do we need to move all the client jars of that respective app server to tomcat lib as well?
very soon I might have to move the ejbs to jboss 7, so I am wondering..

Comment: why just not to take a jboss-all-client.jar? I think its exactly what it has been done for... It should contain everything you need to establish a connection and perform a lookup

Comment: mark, after jboss 4, the jboss-client jar ONLY contains references to other related jars (more than 100 jars are refereed) as I see , these references are the exact set of jars in the jboss_home client folder

(https://community.jboss.org/thread/167201)